# javascript ajax if statement incorrectly returns false

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

after successful connection and receiving the data from php using ajax, I made if statement, which gives false, I don't know why...

javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', action, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (){
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
    var result = xhr.responseText;
    console.log(result); //gives correctly invalid_login_data
    if (result == 'invalid_login_data'){
        console.log("true");  
    }
    else{
        console.log("false");
    }
}
```

php:

```
     <?php
     echo "invalid_login_data";
     ?>
```

the result is "false" instead of "true"

when I write:

```
        <?php
        $result_php = "invalid_login_data";
        echo $result_php;
        ?>
```

is still false

only after:

```
       <?php
       $result_php = 3;
       echo $result_php;
       ?>
```

and changing if satement like this:

```
        if (result == 3){
```

it gives true

what is the reason?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to reproduce the problem. I'd guess that the problem is that `result` contains *white space* in addition to the text you are comparing against.

Comment: Try `console.log(result+".")`- if a dot will be appended after space (as @Quentin suggested) then you have to trim it and everything will be fine

Comment: If the provided example is correct the way you added it, then the spaces in front of the `<php` will be outputted as well, and therefore they wont match

Comment: Seems that the js string comparison [is broken today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46643399/getelementbyid-with-document-reffer) :p

Comment: console.log(result+".") gives "invalid_login_data."

Answer (score 0):

No more informations are provided, so the best we can do is to provide this solution:

replace the if/else block with this:

```
if (result.search('invalid_login_data')>=0){
        console.log("true");  
    }
    else{
        console.log("false");
    }
```

Comment: this gives true, but I don't know why my code gives false

Comment: @gileneusz It gives trues because It searches on your string and if it finds It will return true. Your problem is `whitespace`

Comment: you may be right, but I don't know where is the source if I give "" in exact places and no whitespaces are in the code :)