# getElementByID with document.reffer?

Tags: javascript, php, authentication, credentials

I am new to both Javascript and php. I have a site with a form that goes through some php mumbo jumbo. After that, I check my database to see if the login credentials exist. If they don't, I want to show a div that contains the error message.

```
oldURL = document.referrer;
console.log(oldURL);
if (oldURL =="http://amazingwebsite.com/") {
    document.getElementById("loginfail").removeAttribute("hidden");
    document.getElementById("textlogin").removeAttribute("hidden");
}
```

oldURL returns the exact url that I have in my if statement. However, the if statement only works if I have oldURL to 'not equal' (==!).

What have I missed?

Comment: This looks like something that is much more easily and reliably, achieved with PHP (in the `else` logic for the code which determines if the login was successful).

Comment: what's the output of `console.log(oldURL)`

Comment: @Quentin Should I use 'echo' in php to echo out the div? I tried that but It didnt actually work.

Comment: @taha oldURL returns the exact adress, i.e "http://amazingwebsite.com/".

Comment: Try to log both (oldURL and then your string) and look at the output to figure out why they're different.

Comment: @T30 I get the same URL with both of them.

Comment: It's just a string comparison, [can't be broke](https://jsfiddle.net/j9u7dy5b/2/). There's some difference for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to @T30, I figured it out. Was apparently a problem with the CSS not anything with the php code or the javascript.